# How do I add existing crystal report file in Visual Studio solution C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have developed a windows application in c# using visual studio 2012. I have added the existing crystal report file in the solution. What path should I give in the load path so that it works in the client computer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use client/Sever architecture, Load crystal report from 'server' path and add that path in config file.

Comment: This is a windows application.

Comment: Congigure path in config file. So that it can be modified in client system also.

Comment: I don't think the path is the problem as the application works perfectly on the Dev machine. I am using Application.StartupPath. The problem occurs in the client machine.

Comment: What exception you get in client system? Is Crystal Reports runtime installed on your client's machine?

Comment: Yes. I have installed it. One report works and on the other it gives me error "CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed"

Comment: If one report works in client system, then it might be report specific issue. Is this report works in development system?

Comment: I changed the Font "MICR" for something more classic (Arial) and the reports start to work well.

Apparently this Font has some conflict with Crystal Report export routine.